# In Android 13, when launching Foreground service with notification, what is the correct flow to ensure notification is enabled?

Tags: android

We want to launch a Foreground service, with notification, in Android 13 (API 33)

Starting in Android 13, the following function will return false, for 1st time user.

Based on https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission

> If a user installs your app on a device that runs Android 13 or
> higher, your app's notifications are off by default.

```
public static boolean areNotificationsEnabled() {
    Context context = Application.instance();

    final boolean areNotificationsEnabled = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();

    return areNotificationsEnabled;
}
```

and based on https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission, requesting `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission is not required for Foreground service.

If that is so, may I know, what is the correct flow, to ensure `areNotificationsEnabled` function is returning true?

Is launching the notification activity, the correct flow?

```
public static void launchActionAppNotificationSettings(Fragment fragment, int requestCode) {
    try {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(getLaunchActionAppNotificationSettingsIntent(fragment.getContext()), requestCode);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
}

private static Intent getLaunchActionAppNotificationSettingsIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = null;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);

        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context.getPackageName());
    } else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        intent = new Intent("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");

        intent.putExtra("app_package", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("app_uid", context.getApplicationInfo().uid);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
    }

    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Why do think users need to see a notification for your foreground service to work? They are totally decoupled from one another (which is why users could turn off your notifications for many years now and your foreground service remained unaffected).

Comment: @ianhanniballake that's wrong... You have to provide a notification to the framework in order to start a foreground service. Maybe you're talking about regular services... but foreground ones need a notification.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Based on documentation, isn't a notification is compulsory for Foreground service? - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ForegroundInfo#ForegroundInfo(int,android.app.Notification) A non-null notification object is required.

Comment: @ianhanniballake: "They are totally decoupled from one another (which is why users could turn off your notifications for many years now and your foreground service remained unaffected)" -- citation, please. If it's not documented, then manufacturers are going to change the behavior, as Samsung has done with the behavior of foreground services. Heck, even if it *is* documented we're at risk of manufacturer changes, but at least we have some ammunition to declare that the behavior is a bug.

Comment: You have to define a notification, yes. Whether the user _sees it_ is up to the user and has never had any effect on your app's functionality.

Comment: @ianhanniballake What if, having the notification visible (Because the notification UI contains necessary UI control) is a hard requirement? May I know, what should be the correct flow then? Should we bring user to ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS, or request runtime permission POST_NOTIFICATIONS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure uniform behavior, I suggest

1. add post notifications permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

2. Request  run time permission like usuall:

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 111;

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(YourActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS},REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
       }
```